# Opening a file in append mode but truncating the file if not empty in JAVA 11

Tags: java, append, filewriter, truncation

I would like to create a result.csv file if it does not exist, then I call `write` several times and append corresponding messages one by a call.

But If the file already exists and contain something before the run of the program, I would like to erase its contents and then begin to append corresponding messages .

I have tried the following:

```
public final class Writer {
    public static void write(String message, String destinationPath) {
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(destinationPath, true);
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)
        ) {
            bw.write(message);
            bw.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But, as you may guess, when I run the program over and over it just appends new line on existing ones not erasing what was inside before the program was ran.

the call of `write` is done like:

`studentNamesAndIds.values().forEach(id -> Writer.write(id+","+ DecideGrade.softLookUp(id, studentIdsAndGrades),writeFilePath));`

What should I change to get the result I mentioned at the beginning?

P.S. If I were declaring `new FileWriter(destinationPath)` without the second argument `true` then every call of `write` would erase the content of my file, I would withe the last line inside.

Comment: to open a file in append mode, but, if the file already exists, override its contents - does this even make sense?

Comment: @aran I open a file for writing, I call ```write``` several times during program life cycle to append some content. What can I do else? If I do not specify ```true``` as a second argument in ```FileWriter``` constructor it overrides my file on every call of ```write```. Am I wrong?

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov Please tell us what behaviour you want in the following situations: **Case 1: File already exists and is empty**  _Case 2: File already exists and has some data in it._ **Case 3: File does not exist.**

Comment: “if the file already exists, override its contents” is literally the opposite of appending to a file.  Edit your question and show some short examples of file contents before and after your ideal theoretical code runs.

Comment: I have changed the question a bit, is it clear now what am I trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the job according to your description from the question:

```java
public final class Writer 
{
  private static final Set<String> m_AppendMarkers = new HashMap<>();

  public static void write( final String message, final String destinationPath ) 
  {
    final var append = m_AppendMarkers.contains( destinationPath );
    try( final var fw = new FileWriter( destinationPath, append );
      final var bw = new BufferedWriter( fw ) )
    {
      bw.write( message );
      bw.newLine();
      m_AppendMarkers.add( destinationPath );
    } 
    catch( final IOException e ) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The set will be empty at each restart of the program, therefore `Set::contains` will return `false` for the first attempt to write to the given file; for further attempts, the path to the file was added to the set and the contains check will give you `true`, so further lines will be appended.

But to be honest, although this works, you should consider a different design! So it is not a good idea to open and close a file for each and every new line you write to it.

Also working with a static method is not good design (and that is the reason why you need the `Set` instead of a simple `boolean` flag).

To do it right (or at least a bit better) try this:

```java
public class YourProgram
{
  private static class Writer implements AutoClosable
  {
    private final String m_DestinationPath;
    private final StringJoiner m_Buffer ) = new StringJoiner( "\n", "", "\n" );

    public Writer( final String destinationPath )
    {
      m_DestinationPath = destinationPath;
    }

    @Overwrite
    public final void close() throws IOException
    {
      try( final var writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( m_DestinationPath, false ) ) )
      {
        writer.write( m_Buffer.toString() );
      }
    } 

    public static void write( final String message )
    {
      m_Buffer.add( message );
    }
  }
  //  class Writer

  private static Writer m_Writer;

  public static final void main( final String... args )
  {
    try( var w = new Writer( "TheNameOfYourOutputFile" ) )
    {
      m_Writer = w;

      // Your code goes here …
      …
    }
    catch( final IOException e )
    {
      err.println( "Failed to write the output file" );
      e.printStackTrace( err );
    }
    catch( final Throwable t )
    {
      err.println( "Unhandled exception" );
      t.printStackTrace( err );
    }
  }
}
// class YourProgram
```

Error handling was omitted to keep readability.

As long as you do not attempt to write several GigaBytes of data, this should work much more smoothly than the other design. Ok, it is not crash-save, nothing will be written to the output file if the program will be killed externally.